# HTTP Request in PHP not working for specific API

Tags: php, json, http, request

I have an extremely simple script:

```
<?php
$jsonurl = "http://api.wipmania.com/json";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
echo $json;
?>
```

It works for this URL, but when I call it with this URL: https://erikberg.com/nba/standings.json

it is not echoing the data. What is the reason for this? I'm probably missing a concept here. Thanks

Comment: you have ssl configured properly for this on your server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem for that particular URL is that it's expecting a different User Agent, different to the default that PHP is using with `file_get_contents()`

Here is a better example using CURL. It's more robust although it takes more lines of code to configure it and make it run:

```
// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set the URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://erikberg.com/nba/standings.json');

// Return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// Fake the User Agent for this particular API endpoint
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

// $output contains the output string.
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources.
curl_close($ch);

// You have your JSON response here
echo $output;
```

Comment: Any idea on why this runs so slow?

Comment: From my side it does not run slow at all. That request takes 1.25 secs aprox. Looks like pretty normal response time.

Comment: Ah gotchya, must be something on my end then, it's taking 15+ seconds for me. Thanks again